# Pi stuck in a DHCP loop

Tags: raspbian, networking, debian, dhcp

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, connected to a PC via its ethernet NIC and set to DHCP. `/etc/network/interfaces` on the Pi:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

You're safe to ignore the wifi settings as there are currently no interfaces connected.
On the Debian PC, I have isc-dhcp-server installed and configured. The Pi connects to eth0, which is assigned a static IP. dhcpd starts without problems, but in `/var/log/syslog` I get

```
May 14 16:53:06 danah dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from b8:27:eb:f9:54:da (raspberrypi) via eth0
May 14 16:53:06 danah dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.2 to b8:27:eb:f9:54:da (raspberrypi) via eth0
May 14 16:53:20 danah dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from b8:27:eb:f9:54:da (raspberrypi) via eth0
May 14 16:53:20 danah dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.1.2 to b8:27:eb:f9:54:da (raspberrypi) via eth0
```

and so on, repeatedly. I can't ping the Pi with the IP offered. `dhcpdump -i eth0` gives

```
  TIME: 2015-05-14 16:53:20.960
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (b8:27:eb:f9:54:da) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 897ed007
  SECS: 46
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: b8:27:eb:f9:54:da:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         1 (DHCPDISCOVER)
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        192.168.1.2
OPTION:  12 ( 11) Host name                 raspberrypi
OPTION:  55 ( 13) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                         28 (Broadcast address)
                          2 (Time offset)
                          3 (Routers)
                         15 (Domainname)
                          6 (DNS server)
                        119 (Domain Search)
                         12 (Host name)
                         44 (NetBIOS name server)
                         47 (NetBIOS scope)
                         26 (Interface MTU)
                        121 (Classless Static Route)
                         42 (NTP servers)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2015-05-14 16:53:20.961
    IP: 192.168.1.100 (e8:11:32:3d:a2:1) > 192.168.1.2 (b8:27:eb:f9:54:da)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 897ed007
  SECS: 46
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.1.2
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: b8:27:eb:f9:54:da:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         2 (DHCPOFFER)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.1.100
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      600 (10m)
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         192.168.1.255
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.1.1
OPTION:  15 ( 11) Domainname                example.org
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and so on. 
`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` on the server has:

```
# Set up our desired subnet:
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.0 192.168.1.254;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option routers 192.168.1.1;
    authoritative;
}
```

What's going on? I checked the Raspberry Pi SD card, but there's no `/var/log/syslog`, so I don't know if `dhclient` is receiving the offer.
Just to make it more frustrating, it worked once, the first time I tried it. I was able to ssh to the Pi, but the connection froze, and since then it's been stuck in this state. I've tried tweaking the configuration, but to no avail.

Comment: I accidentally firewalled off my DHCP replies once. After I fixed my firewall, the problem went away. It's a long shot, Rpi doesn't ship with a firewall by default. I did this to myself... but on the off chance that it helps :-)

Comment: Just an observation not an answer. To me, it looks like you have a very short lease time. Is the time kept for each MAC? That would explain it working once.

Comment: Your dhcp address range looks wtong to me, can you change it to `range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.254;` and try again?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this once with a pfSense box.  The issue wound up being that both the pfSense and the Pi had auto-MDI-X and somehow that failed.  The pfSense side was working, so I could see pfSense respond with a DHCPoffer, but the Pi would not see it.

I put in a switch and the Pi was happy.  If you have the same situation, you could presumably use a crossover cable, but you still might get tripped up by auto-MDIX.

You can read about that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266283/raspbian-jessie-wired-lan-no-dhcpoffers-from-pfsense-2-2-6-dhcp-server).